# Common Floating Action Button across different tabs of the action bar (pre lollipop)

Tags: android, button, android-fragments, action, floating

I am using a simple button with an xml background as a floating action button. 
I have the fixed tab navigation mode for my activity.
I had to add the button separately for all the different tab fragment layouts. 
Is there a way to set the button as fixed, common and non-swipe-able? So that it remains the same for all the different fragment layouts representing different tabs?

Comment: Declare  your `Floating Action Button` in Activity layout instead of your fragment layout.